# How should I load a memory-intensive helper object per-worker in dask distributed?

Tags: python, dask, spacy, dask-distributed

I am currently trying to parse a very large number of text documents using [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/#) + [spaCy](https://spacy.io/). SpaCy requires that I load a relatively large `Language` object, and I would like to load this once per worker. I have a couple of mapping functions that I would like to apply to each document, and I would hopefully not have to reinitialize this object for each future / function call. What is the best way to handle this?

Example of what I'm talking about:

```py
def text_fields_to_sentences(
    dataframe:pd.DataFrame,
    ...
)->pd.DataFrame:
  # THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE
  nlp, = setup_spacy(scispacy_version)

  def field_to_sentences(row):
    result = []
    doc = nlp(row[text_field])
    for sentence_tokens in doc.sents:
      sentence_text = "".join([t.string for t in sentence_tokens])
      r = text_data.copy()
      r[sentence_text_field] = sentence_text
      result.append(r)
    return result
  series = dataframe.apply(
    field_to_sentences,
    axis=1
  ).explode()
  return pd.DataFrame(
      [s[new_col_order].values for s in series],
      columns=new_col_order
  )

input_data.map_partitions(text_fields_to_sentences)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the object as a delayed object

```
corpus = dask.delayed(make_corpus)("english")
```

And then use this lazy value in place of the full value:

```
df = df.text.apply(parse, corpus=corpus)
```

Dask will call `make_corpus` once on one machine and then pass it around to the workers as it is needed.  It will not recompute any task.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. But what should I do when that object can't be picked?